# Docker Postgres container is not starting for Rails Application

Tags: ruby, docker, ruby-on-rails-4, docker-compose

I am facing an issue on docker container. When I execute the `docker-compose up` to start the application the Postgres container is not starting.

**Error which I get after docker-compose up**

`` /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known (PG::ConnectionBad) ``

Now it is frequently happing. I tried with few steps as add ports for `db` container i.e `5432:5432`. I used to start-stop the specific db container so that the connection should get re-established but it is not working.

Application details:

Rails Version: 4.2.0 Ruby version: 2.2.0

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-krypton
    ports: ['4444:4444', '5900:5900']
    logging:
      driver: none
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.0
  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:1.5.2
  db:
    image: postgres:9.3.10
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - .:/home
  XYZ:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - XYZ-sync:/home:nocopy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - elastic
      - selenium
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=elastic://elastic:9200/0
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium
      - SELENIUM_PORT=4444
      - TEST_APP_HOST=XYZ
      - TEST_PORT=3000
```

db log

```
db_1          | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-10 07:37:08 UTC
db_1          | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1          | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1          | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1          | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1          | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1          | LOG:  shutting down
db_1          | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1          | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-10 07:37:50 UTC
db_1          | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1          | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1          | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1          | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-09-10 07:38:31 UTC
db_1          | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1          | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-09-10 07:38:31 UTC
db_1          | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1          | LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1D8F0120
db_1          | LOG:  redo is not required
db_1          | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1          | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1          | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1          | LOG:  stats_timestamp 2019-09-10 08:02:39.288642+00 is later than collector's time 2019-09-10 08:02:39.189551+00 for database 0
db_1          | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-09-10 08:18:02 UTC
db_1          | FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

`docker-compose ps` output

```
xyz_db_1           /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up       5432/tcp                                      
xyz_elastic_1      /docker-entrypoint.sh elas ...   Up       9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                            
xyz_xyz_1   bash -c rm -f tmp/pids/ser ...   Exit 1                                                 
xyz_redis_1        /entrypoint.sh redis-server      Up       6379/tcp                                      
xyz_selenium_1     /opt/bin/entry_point.sh          Up       0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp
```

`database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default
  database: XYZ_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: XYZ_test

development_migrate:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: xyz_ee
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to expose ports 5432:5432 in the compose

Comment: could you please provide logs from `docker-compose logs db`

Comment: also `docker-compose ps` would be helpful

Comment: @JakubBujny I updated the question for the details what you asked

Comment: can you share your `config/database.yml` please?
by the way you don't need to expose port 5432 because containers inside docker-compose's network are already available to each other. you only need to expose a port if you want access something from a host machine

Comment: @user3309314 updated the same. I tried with expose also but it didn't worked for me

Comment: you can also try the command `docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres` to get into postgres console just to make sure your database container is up and postgres is runnning

Comment: Have you tried using a script like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to wrap so that postgres starts before rails tries to connect? Could be a timing issue

Comment: @JayDorsey thanks for your suggestion, yes the db container is started before the web container. I resolved this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with the help of @jayDosrsey suggestion.
The DB container get started before the main web container and hence it always gets failed to start the container and I again need to restart the web container.

Resolved this issue by adding the health check condition while starting the rails server.

```
XYZ:
  build: .
  command: bash -c "while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"

  ...

Now I am able to start the container in sequence.
```